# Register to GCM in background

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-2.0.0

what I'm trying to do is run some scripts let say "in background" and display external page.

I have my activity

```
public class MyApp extends DroidGap
{
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        //super.loadUrl("http://external.com/");
    }
}
```

I'm able now only to load my internal page where scripts are included or load external url.

What I want to do is

```
public class MyApp extends DroidGap
{
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // run my gcm script to register
        super.loadUrl("http://external.com/"); //load prepared page
    }
}
```

but I don't know if script should/can be run from java code. Or maybe this is wrong solution and I should load my external page from js? I'm using cordova 2.5

Comment: Hi Meryl, have you checked the GCM Phonegap plugin? [check here](https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova)

Answer (score 0):

If you planning to support IOS (APNS) and Android (GCM), you can use PushPlugin https://github.com/bobeast/PushPlugin

It is easy to setup, where you can register for GCM using javascript and having the same interface for Android and IOS.

Comment: I'm also going to support Windows Phone

Comment: What windows use for the push notification?